# Getting event from eventId in Swift not working

Tags: swift, eventkit

In my `CalendarEventsManager` class, I use singleton to save an `Event`. I ommit calendar access permissions code here, which work OK:

```
import SwiftUI
import EventKit    

final class CalendarEventsManager {
   static let shared = CalendarEventsManager()
   let eventStore = EKEventStore()

    // More code here to define event properties.
   
    do {
     try CalendarEventsManager.shared.eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
       print("Event saved on calendar, with eventId: \(event.eventIdentifier ?? "")")
   } catch {
     print("Error saving event: \(error)")
   }
```

This way, I obtain `event.eventIdentifier` string printed with no problem at all.

But later, when trying to retrieve back this `Event` from its `eventIdentifier`, I get a `nil` value:

```
if let event = CalendarEventsManager.shared.eventStore.event(withIdentifier: eventId ?? "") {
  print("EventID: \(event.eventIdentifier ?? "")") // <- Nil here.
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm trying with `event.calendarItemIdentifier` property too, with the same result. Do this `ids` change when closing the app? They seem to work maintaining app open.

Updated 12/11/2023 - 18:05.

After @matt response, here you have complete `CalendarEventsManager` class with his suggestion. It works when trying to retrieve events **not closing the app**. After restarting the app, **any event identifier seems to change**.

```
import SwiftUI
import EventKit

/// The class responsible of managing addition and deletion of system calendar events when adding, updating or deleting app rehearsals.
final class CalendarEventsManager {
  @AppStorage("savingsCalendar") var savingsCalendar = ""
  @AppStorage("rehearsalsDuration") var rehearsalsDuration = 900
  @AppStorage("eventsAlarmsOn") var eventsAlarmsOn = false
  @AppStorage("eventsAlarmsTime") var eventsAlarmsTime = 900
  
  // Singletons in order to keep the same EKEventStore instance app-wide. I think it's not necessary, anyway.
  static let shared = CalendarEventsManager()
  static let eventStore = EKEventStore()
  
  /// Adds an event to system calendar from a ``Rehearsal``.
  /// - Parameter rehearsal: Related ``Rehearsal``.
  func createEvent(from rehearsal: Rehearsal) {
    let event = EKEvent(eventStore: CalendarEventsManager.eventStore)
    
    event.title = NSLocalizedString("Rehearsal with ", comment: "") + (rehearsal.relatedStudent?.name)! + " (" + (rehearsal.relatedStudent?.relatedInstrument?.name)! + ")"
    event.startDate = rehearsal.date
    event.endDate = rehearsal.date?.addingTimeInterval(TimeInterval(rehearsalsDuration))
    
    if eventsAlarmsOn {
      let time = Double(eventsAlarmsTime)
      let alarm = EKAlarm(relativeOffset: -time)
      event.alarms = [alarm]
    }
    
    var worksInfo: String = ""
    var relatedWorks = [Work]()
    if rehearsal.relatedWorks?.count ?? 0 > 0 {
      for work in Array(rehearsal.relatedWorks as! Set<Work>) {
        relatedWorks.append(work)
      }
      worksInfo.append(relatedWorks.map{ "\($0.relatedComposer?.name ?? ""): \($0.title ?? "")"}.joined(separator: "\r"))
    }
    
    let notes = (rehearsal.notes.nilIfEmpty != nil) ? rehearsal.notes ?? "" : ""
    let publicInfo = rehearsal.inPublic ? NSLocalizedString("Public", comment: "") : ""
    let footText = NSLocalizedString("This is a copy of a CompingApp rehearsal. Any changes will not take any effect on app data.", comment: "")
    event.notes = "\(worksInfo)\r\(notes)\r\(publicInfo)\r---\r\(footText)"
    
    event.calendar = CalendarEventsManager.eventStore.calendar(withIdentifier: savingsCalendar)
    
    do {
      try CalendarEventsManager.eventStore.save(event, span: .thisEvent)
    } catch {
      print("Error saving event: \(error)")
    }
    
    /// Using calendarItemIdentifier, as eventIdentifier seems not to be reliable. But this values SEEM TO CHANGE anyway.
    rehearsal.setValue(event.calendarItemIdentifier, forKey: "eventId")
    
  }
  
  /// Deletes the event in system calendar related to a ``Rehearsal``.
  /// - Parameter rehearsal: Related ``Rehearsal``.
  func deleteEvent(for rehearsal: Rehearsal) {
    
    if let event = CalendarEventsManager.eventStore.calendarItem(withIdentifier: rehearsal.eventId ?? "") {
      do {
        try CalendarEventsManager.eventStore.remove(event as! EKEvent, span: .thisEvent, commit: true)
      } catch {
        print("Error deleting event: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What if you call `calendarItem(withIdentifier:)` instead? — Also, could you show us more about how `event` is defined / created?

Comment: Question edited for you to have more context.

Comment: "It works when trying to retrieve events not closing the app. After restarting the app, any event identifier seems to change." That is correct and expected.

Comment: In fact the identifier can change even while your app is running.

Comment: So… how could I retrieve that event? Is it impossible?

Comment: @arroyot24, Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, still waiting. It’s sooo strange not being able to get an event from its id that I’m thinking sending an enquiry directly to Apple.